# How do I use chained `css()` calls so the selector in the second call uses the first call as the context?

Tags: scrapy, css-selectors

I'm processing a table row-by-row and need to sniff the `id`s of the rows:

```
<table id="tbl">
  <tr id="row_1">
    <td id="cell_1">...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row_2">
    <td id="cell_2">...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So my code looks something like:

```
def parse_table(self, response):
    rows = response.css('#tbl > tr')
    for row in rows:
        rowid = row.css('::attr(id)')
        if rowid.extract_first().startswith('row'):
            ...
```

However, this way, the second call to `.css()` gives me IDs of all the descendants of `row`, not just its direct children. I.e. for the above example HTML, it returns `"cell_1"` as well as `"row_1"`. How do I scope the chained `css()` call so it only acts on direct children of the given row?

I've tried using the `:scope` pseudo-class but that doesn't seem to be supported by Scrapy, and `:root` gives me no results.

Alternately, can I just get the value of the `id` attribute without going through CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can show you how to use XPath for the same task:

```
def parse_table(self, response):
    for row in response.xpath('//*[@id="tbl"]/tr'):
        rowid = row.xpath('./@id').extract_first()
        if rowid.startswith('row'):
            ...
```

Comment: This is what I'm going with I guess, I just could've sworn I've seen a CSS way to do this when looking for some other issue and I guess my brain got stuck on it.

Comment: Is there a reason to use "./" here? It seems that just leaving it out is implied.

Comment: @millimoose The '.' at the beginning means, that the current processing starts at the current node.

Comment: I assumed as much, but near as I can tell that’s already implied when chaining `xpath` calls and I couldn’t find any difference in behaviour while poking around things in scrapy shell between the two

Comment: I like keeping the `'./'` at the beginning because, although it is unnecessary, it makes easier to understand the current context and avoid make mistakes when queries like `.//p`